# Livepatch on 20.04 LTS - Failed to retreive Livepatch status

Tags: lts, 20.04, canonical-livepatch

I just installed/upgraded to 20.04 LTS from 18.04.  Livepatch is enabled but fails to show up in the task/menu bar area.  In Software and updates, Livepatch shows as on but also says 'Failed to retrieve Livepatch status'

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: I have the same problem (Ubuntu 20.09). Hope someone is able to help.

Comment: @Duncan Is 20.09 a beta of Groovy?
I believe Livepatch is only supported on LTS versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: I think my Ubuntu 20.04 is LTS

Answer (score 1):

I ended up uninstalling the Livepatch snap, rebooting and reinstalling the Livepatch snap.  Once I logged on to Livepatch with my Ubuntu account my problem was resolved.